# How can I have SQL Server listening on more than one IP address?

Tags: sql-server

I have a an SQL server that normally listens on a private IP address (10.x.x.x). However, I would like to be able to connect to the database over the public (31.x.x.x). I tried to enable this tonight, but when I restarted the SQL Server service, the server wasn't listening on the internal IP address any more.

I was using the configuration manager to let the SQL Server know the IP addresses it should be listening on.

I am running SQL Server 2008R Standard.

Comment: Is the public IP configured on one of the NIC cards of the server?

Comment: Yes, it just seemed to happen after I'd configured it to listen on two IPs (the private one and the public one)

Answer (score 3):

On the Protocol tab of configuration manager, there is a "Listen All" option, make sure that is set to yes.

Keep in mind that having an active listener on a public connection is asking for trouble, best to do it over a VPN, or filter allowed incoming connections by IP address, or at least use something other than the default port.

Comment: I've got Windows firewall running and locking it down by IP.

Comment: Also, I've already got Listen All set to yes

Comment: Stop and start SQL service if you haven't. Check the SQL Logs in management studio from the last startup, it will list the IP addresses it is listening on. Also check netstat -an